# Facebook. Получить имя/фамилию на латинице, используя Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-api

Необходимо получить эту информацию на латинице

Comment: `locale=en_US` к параметрам запроса пробовали добавить? Подробности [здесь](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/)

Comment: Да, пробовал, не помогло

Comment: так пример приведите как вы это используете, в graph api explorer все нормально работает. [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24903860/4041128), кстати, тоже про это пишут

Comment: Такой запрос: https://graph.facebook.com/{uid}?access_token={token}&fields=first_name,last_name&locale=en_US

Comment: Попробовал в Graph Api Explorer использовать `locale=en_US` - все равно выдает в кириллице.

Comment: возможно, баг, я нашел у себя несколько друзей, для которых информация возвращается только в одной локализации (либо русской, либо английской), при этом для большинства локализация все же работает. У них как-то [была уже такая проблема](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/697517653622499/). Попробуйте написать им, может и исправят

Comment: @BOPOH спасибо за помощь.

Comment: так у вас что-нибудь получилось исправить? может поделитесь результатами? если баг завели, то ссылку на баг бы скинули, как там ответят - можно будет и здесь отписаться

Comment: Позже скину, как напишу им.

Comment: вы обещали скинуть результаты )

Comment: Решил самостоятельно менять на латиницу. :)